# Filter based on multiple select in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to filter my users table using multiple select? I've tried changing it to just single selection and the filter works and it's properly executing the sql but i want to change it to multiple select. I've tried it and the filter is not working. How can I accomplish it?

I have this in my form:

```
<%= f.label :department_id %><br>
<%= f.select :department_id, Department.all.map { |d| [d.name, d.id] }, {include_blank: true}, multiple: true %>
```

After the form has been submitted, it executes a function in its model. This is the piece of code that made the single selection work but it won't work in multiple selection: `users = User.where(["users.department_id = ?", department_id]) if department_id.present?`. How can I make it work on multiple selection?

Edit: I've noticed that it's not returning anything when it's multiple select. How can i fix this?

Comment: `users.where(department_id: department_id)`

Comment: `Users.where(department_id: params[:department_id])`

Comment: _"... it executes a function in its model ..."_ - @iGian you don't have access to `params` inside a model.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, does it skip the controller?

Comment: @iGian this line of code is present in model and models don't know about `params`.

Answer (score 0):

Its similar approach even for multiple select.

Lets say you want to filter using department and location:

```
<%= f.label :department_id %><br>
<%= f.select :department_id, Department.all.map { |d| [d.name, d.id] }, {include_blank: true}, multiple: true %>
<%= f.label :location_id %><br>
<%= f.select :location_id, Location.all.map { |d| [d.name, d.id] }, {include_blank: true}, multiple: true %>
```

Change the function in your model to have the following content:

```
@users = User.where(["department_id = ?", department_id]) if department_id.present?
@users = @users.where(["location_id = ?", location_id]) if location_id.present?
```

In the above, first line filters using department. In the second line, it filters the already filtered users with location.

Comment: for some reason, it is still not working. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: i have noticed that the multiple select is not returning its value `department_id`. how can i fix this?

Comment: What are the params you are getting?

Comment: the department_id is returning NULL

Comment: try `<%= f.select :department_id, Department.all.map { |d| [d.name, d.id] }, {include_blank: true, multiple: true} %>` and tell me if it still happens

Comment: it became a single selection which is working from the start.

Comment: You try using select_tag instead of f.select

Comment: It is still the same. I've noticed that when adding the `multiple: true` in it the name of the select changes from `filter_user[department_id]` to  `filter_user[department_id][]`. is there anyway to call `filter_user[department_id][]` in the model?

Comment: Can you post the params you are seeing?